# How to find files that contain MULTIPLE newlines at their end?

Tags: macos, file, unix, find, newline

I want to find all files that have multiple new line characters at the end of their content.

How is this possible?

Comment: why do you need this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI: It's possible to search for this with PHPStorm using RegEx search term `\n+\n\Z`

Answer (score 1):

This bash command prints all files in current directory and its subdirectories that terminate with at least one empty line at the end after a sequence of one or more lines (i.e. at least a sequence of two \n):

```
 find . -type f -print | while read a; do tail -2 "$a" | ( read x && read y && [ x"$x" = x ] && [ x"$y" = x ] && echo "$a" ); done
```

Comment: Actually I had to add `&& [ x"$y" = x ]` to check that both last lines are empty. Thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: I confirm it's missing `&& [ x"$y" = x ]` @giuseppe-guerrini could you edit your answer?